# python script to add specified file to crontab

Tags: python, cron

I want to create python script that automatically adds specified file to crontab on raspberry pi.
Something along these lines:
(shurley my command doesn't work, it's just a hint on how i want it to work)

```
file = "/home/pi/test/python_script.py &"
def add_to_crontab(file):
   system("echo @reboot python {} >> crontab -e".format(file))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>>` is for redirecting to a file, not a command. Use `|` to pipe to a command.

`crontab` -e is for editing the crontab interactively. To edit it  automatically, you need to extract the current crontab to a file, append the new line to the file, then update the crontab from that file.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

def add_to_crontab(file):
    with os.popen("crontab -l", "r") as pipe:
        current = pipe.read()
    current += f"@reboot python {file}\n"
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w") as f:
        f.write(current)
        f.flush()
        system(f"crontab {f.name}")
```